# copy paste filtered data not working as expected

Tags: vba, excel

First things first. I am very new to VBA. 
Secondly, I googled my ass of and I honestly don't get to the bottom of it. Mostly because the code is adapted to my needs based on googleing i did (copy/paste of code).

To my problem. I have a sheet(Raw Data) with lots of columns(A:AN) and lots of rows(160000) that gets updated every now and then. I want to filter the dataset based on the criteria from a few columns(A & B), and the copy/paste the data in a different sheet(Scatter Raw) starting from column A. I also do not want to copy the header from "Raw Data" and start pasting in "Scatter Sheet" also below the header -> in this case 2 rows.

I have two issues for now:

1. Based on the filters I do, I will get 17267 rows in "Raw Data". If I simply do a select and copy then I copy only the filtered data. But the moment I paste the data somehow I suddenly get 18362 rows, even though they are empty. I can see this by the fact that the scroll bar goes down. I used this way of copying because sometimes I want to be able to append the copied data based on value set in a different cell. What am I doing here wrong, or what is happening?
2. I have more sheets inside the workbook. If I do not have the Raw Data worksheet selected I get an error like "Application-defined or object-defined error" on the "Set rng = " line which I don't get. In other test I also got a different error, but that was because the Range was based on the active sheet and not the one I needed. Why is this happening, since the filters are correctly set?

The values from column N should all be divided by 1000. I guess I have no other way then using a temporary copy column, divide it by 1000 in a new column and then copy/paste the new values to the location I need in, right?

Just one last mention, the code is running in a Module and will be later assigned to a button.

```
Sub Copy()
  Dim destTrSheet As Worksheet
  Dim sctrSheet As Worksheet

  Set destTrSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Raw")
  Set sctrSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Raw")

  With destTrSheet
    .Range("A:A").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="VF", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Range("B:B").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="CITY", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Set Rng = .Range("N2").Resize(Cells(Rows.count, "N").End(xlUp).Row - 1)
    Rng.Copy
    sctrSheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    Set Rng = .Range("X2").Resize(Cells(Rows.count, "N").End(xlUp).Row - 1)
    Rng.Copy
    sctrSheet.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues you mentioned

1. Discrepancy between manual copy and code copy could be caused by the offsets used:

   - Col A `.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial` - 1 row below last used row
   - Col B `.Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial` - 2 rows below last used row
2. The error is caused by `.Range("N2")` vs `(Cells(Rows.count, "N")`

   - `.Range("N2")` is explicitly qualified because of the dot (**`.`**) - refers to `"Data Raw"`
   - `Cells(Rows.count, "N")` is implicitly referring to `ActiveSheet` (missing **`.`**)
3. If column N should be divided by 1000

   - Yes, a helper column can be used, as in the code bellow
   - Another way: copy the column to an array, divide each value, then paste it back

If column N contains strings, the division will generate cell errors:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRawToScatter()
    Dim wsR As Worksheet:       Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Raw")
    Dim wsS As Worksheet:       Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Raw")
    Dim lrR As Long:            lrR = wsR.Cells(wsR.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lrS As Long:            lrS = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With wsR
        Dim fRng As Range:      Set fRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(lrR, "B"))
        Dim rngN As Range:      Set rngN = .Range(.Cells(2, "N"), .Cells(lrR, "N"))
        Dim rngX As Range:      Set rngX = .Range(.Cells(2, "X"), .Cells(lrR, "X"))
        Dim cRng As Range:      Set cRng = Union(rngN, rngX)
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    fRng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="VF", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    fRng.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="CITY", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    If fRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 2 Then
        cRng.Copy
        wsS.Cells(lrS, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        With wsS
            Dim vis As Long:    vis = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Dim lcS As Long:    lcS = .Cells(lrS, "A").End(xlToRight).Column + 1
            Dim divA As Range:  Set divA = .Range(.Cells(lrS, "A"), .Cells(vis, "A"))
            Dim divX As Range:  Set divX = .Range(.Cells(lrS, lcS), .Cells(vis, lcS))

            divX.Formula = "=" & .Cells(lrS, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & " / 1000"
            divA.Value2 = divX.Value2
            divX.ClearContents
        End With
    End If
    wsR.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

---

Other issues

- Potential conflict between your Sub name (`Copy()`) with the built-in `Range.Copy` Method
- The 2 AutoFilter lines are invalid

  - `.Range("A:A").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="VF", Operator:=xlFilterValues`
  - `.Range("B:B").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="CITY", Operator:=xlFilterValues`
  - If your code works you probably modified it when posting the question; they should be
  - `.Range("A:B").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="VF", Operator:=xlFilterValues`
  - `.Range("A:B").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="CITY", Operator:=xlFilterValues`
- You don't need brackets for `.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)`

Comment: Hi Paul. Many thanks for your reply and explanations.
1) you may be right. I used the offset 2 on the second copy because column B did not have a header -> was my judgement correct?. Anyway, now I added a header to column B as well and tested with offset 1 for both columns -> no more spaces at the end of the copied data

Comment: 2) I admit I read about this and did some trials but instea of (.Cells I used the dim-ed worksheet name before ".". Somewhere I must have done something wrong because it also did not work as expected -> working now

Comment: 3) I will give it a go with your solution. But I am not yet familiar with arrays and how they work -> will read into it.
4) The Sub(Copy) name was just for this post, I actually use Sub test_Data().
5) I did not change anything on the AutoFilter lines and they were working.

Comment: Hi Paul. I ran into a new issue while using your code. Maybe you could help. I'll post below as an answer to my question becuase it's too much text.